# Did Wubi damage my RAID-1 array?

Tags: wubi, raid

After installing Ubuntu I found [the helpful WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/) that informed me that RAID configurations are not supported by this Wubi installation of Ubuntu.  Still, the Wubi installer appears to have worked, at least initially.

My first attempt to boot to Ubuntu was successful, but then all subsequent attempts take me to grub terminal.  Windows still boots without trouble.

The size of the root.disk file is 0, but it exists.  I'm not sure if that's normal or if it was corrupted or what... but based on the guide I used the windows command `chkdsk /R` to check my disk.  It found many errors, but it didn't produce a "found.000" file that I could find.

**Is it possible that running Ubuntu in this unsupported RAID1 configuration would cause data corruption problems to files available through the Windows OS?**  I backed up my most important files, so I could restore specific files if they are corrupt.  I have no idea how to interpret the [windows chkdsk log](http://geneorama.com/uploaded/chkdsk%20log%20HP%2020120703.txt), perhaps this would give some indication about which files (if any) were damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES - running Wubi on top of an unsupported storage configuration can absolutely cause damage!**  That's why you are told it's *not supported*!

The data corruption certainly affects the underlying NTFS file system, and files on it. `root.disk` was file in Windows, and it got *wiped* out, right?

All the chkdsk log is saying is that there were a lot of errors in the Master File Table, or index of files. The file data itself may have been unaffected, but the file system now may have no idea of *where* to find that data.

I recommend you restore files from backup as you notice they are missing.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if root.disk was supposed to be 0 kb or not. I thought maybe it was an empty container that was used after you booted into Ubuntu.  Also, since there was no warning about RAID, I wasn't sure if "not supported" meant "will totally jack you".  It took a while to find that installation guide.  It's disappointing that there are no system requirements that I could see on the installer download page.  Anyway... thanks for the reply.